# What is meant by $[U, U_\perp]$ are unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

I know that a complex matrix $U$ is unitary if $U^\ast U = UU^\ast = I$.

In [0910.0651](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.0651.pdf), the author writes (see page 8)

> ... pick $U_\perp$, $V_\perp$ such that $[U, U_\perp]$ and $[V, V_\perp]$ are unitary matrices...

What does that notation mean? Additionally, in context, (see page 8), how is the existence of these matrices guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further up the paper, in section 2, $\mathbf{U}_{\perp}$ is introduced as the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf{U}.$ And, the notation $[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]$ is used for a block matrix with hypercolumns $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ (it's used for vectors in section 2).

I haven't read through the paper, but here are some thoughts:
Since orthogonal complements are not unique, the degree of freedom may be used to complete $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ to unitary matrices, i.e.

$$\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{U}_{\perp})^\top\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{0},$$

where $\mathbf{M}$ is the degree of freedom and can be chosen arbitrarily (invertible). $\mathbf{U}_{\perp}(\mathbf{M})^\top$ will be an orthogonal complement, too. Now, depending on $\mathbf{U},$ the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ may be chosen such that $[\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{U}_{\perp}(\mathbf{M})^\top]$ is unitary.

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing now that essentially $U_\perp$ is Gram-Schmidt/i.e., completion of the orthonormal basis to $U^\perp$ since the columns of $U$ span the subspace $U$ of  $\mathbf{R}^n$

Comment: So, does this answer your question then?

Comment: upon actually reading the rest of your comments (i.e., the part saying that though $U^\perp$ is unique, its basis is not) yeah.

Comment: Sure, the basis is not unique, and it depends if the author uses $\mathbf{U}_{\perp}$ as the space, or an element from the space..I believe you understand what the author of the paper is referring to, though.